# Fast charging a Samsung S4/S5 with an Apple charger

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-4, charging, samsung-galaxy-s-5

Does anyone know if it's possible to achieve fast charging (1300mA+) a S4/S5/S6 with an iPhone (5/6) charger? The data pins have a circuit, but I believe Apple uses a different voltage divider to Samsung.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I haven't ever heard of a way to adapt iphone cord to a Samsung, and Apple is particularly exclusive to themselves, they don't play well with others. But anything is achievable.  The S4 has the standard usb 2.o cord, and isn't as fast as the laters. The S5 & S6 come with the usb 3.0 cord and the wall adapter that is a fast charging set up, it'll be as fast as the iphone cord. The usb 3.o and apple lighting cord are basically the same thing (charging/data transfer), the only difference is that the lighting cord's advantage is that it can plug in to the phone in either direction, meaning it cannot be upside down. Also the S5/6's factory 3.0 usb cord charging performance is regulated by the wall adapter. Wall adapters' have output ratings, for example, if the one that comes with the phone is lost and then an old  used one that has an one amp output is used, then the phone will not charge as fast as the stock setup.